# C++ Multidimension array and Pointer name bracketing

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

There have been a lot of questions about C++ Multidimension arrays asked already, although none have either A) fully explained what I'm trying to ask here or B) Maybe I just didn't understand it.

My issue:

```
int (*ip)[4];
```

The issue I have is understanding the reason of adding brackets around *ip in this situation.  Looking at Multidimensional arrays:

```
int ia[3][4];
int *ip = &ia[2];
int *ip2[4] = &ia[2];
int (*ip3)[4] = &ia[2];
```

ip, ip2, and ip3 are all *intended* to point to the first element of the array at position ia[2].

1. *ia[2]* is just a pointer to the first element of that array, and so *&ia[2]* is the address of that pointer? Correct?
2. It would seem to me that *ip* could be used as it would work in the same way a char * would work... yes? no?
3. it makes sense to me that *ip2* is incorrect.  It makes sense to me that *ip2* is an array of pointers that point to ints when what I want here is a pointer to an array of ints.
4. I know *ip3* is correct. Why? Because the book says so. That's it really. I don't understand the significance of the bracketing.

So how do the brackets change things? I'm really after a conceptual explanation here so I can understand and reuse this concept in future.

Thanks again for your time everyone, and I'm still new here so if there is anything I can do to improve my question please let me know.

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) might help you some in the future

Comment: The 4th is correct because in c++ operator[] has mo priority than operator* so you get an array of 4 pointers to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The first one:

   ```
   int *ip = &ia[2];
   ```

   is invalid.  `&ia[2]` is the address of an `int[4]`, therefore it is of type `int (*)[4]`, and so can't be used to initialise an `int *`.  You could, however, write this:

   ```
   int *ip = ia[2];
   ```

   which now does what you expect.
2. No, see above.
3. Indeed.
4. It is correct because that is the correct syntax.  Start from the middle and work outwards.  `(*ip3)` means `ip3` is a pointer to something.  Working outwards, the thing it is a pointer to is an `int[4]`.

Comment: Really? I would expect `&ia[2]` to be of the type `int (*)[4]`, like the OP.  I'm wrong more often than you though.

Comment: @Mooing: Yes, that's a typo on my part!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much. The "start from the middle and work outwards" sentence is what solidifies it in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are to indicate who is the pointer.

```
int *ip1[4];
int (*ip2)[4];
```

`ip1` is an array of 4 pointers to `int`.
`ip2` is a pointer to array of 4 `int`s.